# Regular expression or sprintf-like function to format strings in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a set of strings that I'd like to display in a specific format:

```
| Type     | Example    | Regex                   | Output         |
|----------|------------|-------------------------|----------------|
| Ref      | 0909090    | [0-9]{8}                | "09090909"     |
| Identity | 6001002003 | [0-9]{10}               | "600 100 2003" |
| Internal | M12/45678  | [Mm][0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4,8} | "M12 / 45678"  |
```

Is there a function in PHP that would allow me to pass something *like* a regular expression *or* a `sprintf` string that would allow me to format a string in a particular way.

It doesn't **need** to be either of those, but it **does** need to be able to be specified as a string.  This is so I can store it in some kind of data object that will look like:

```
[
   {
      name: "identity",
      regex: "[0-9]{10}",
      format: "%3c %3c %4c" /* or whatever it ends up being */
   },
   // ....
]
```

The function should work *along the lines of*:

```
echo formatMyString('6001002003', '%3c %3c %4c') // returns "600 100 2003"
```

Comment: Post the actual code where you want to use this because as it stands, this question isn't very clear about what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @WillardSolutions - added a bit more clarification as to the expected input and output.

Comment: Why are you looking for something else than `sprintf`?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  A regex of `[0-9]{10}` doesn't really make sense if you need three parts.  You'd probably be better off writing functions to handle each format rather than doing something dynamic like this.

Comment: @NicoHaase - does ``sprintf`` format characters? (see last example)

Comment: @Devon - the 3 parts are purely to make it more human-readable.  You'd expect it to be entered as 10 consecutive digits (because people are lazy and don't *need* to type spaces for it to be understood), but for printing out you'd want those digits separated out, since that's the usual form the identifier is printed as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` with `preg_match` check before applying it. Example:

```
function formatMyString($string) {
    $patterns = [
        [
            'name' => 'identity',
            'regex' => '^([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})$',
            'format' => '$1 $2 $3'
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($patterns as $pattern) {
        if (preg_match('/'.$pattern['regex'].'/', $string)) {
            return preg_replace('/'.$pattern['regex'].'/', $pattern['format'], $string);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have used a slightly altered version of this - added a ``!== false`` check for the ``preg_match`` call, and just used the bit inside the ``foreach`` loop ... but it works perfectly.  Thanks :)

Comment: @AlgyTaylor, `preg_match()` returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred. If you only use `!== false` it will let non-matches slip through and will break the logic.